# Arriving very late at hotels in Athens

Tags: athens, late-arrival

This September, I will be flying into Athens at 10:45 PM.  I'll be leaving to Santorini, then arriving back towards the end of the week via Piraeus at 11:45 PM.

Will arriving that late in town pose any problem traveling to Athenian Callirhoe Exclusiv near the  Parthenon?  Will checkin be a problem?

I see that the hotel is near a metro stop and a bus stop, so hopefully one of those will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last Line 1 metro [leaves Piraeus at 00:15](http://www.stasy.gr/index.php?id=67&L=1), so you're cutting it awfully close even if your ferry arrives precisely on time, and it doesn't pass very close to your hotel anyway (you'd need to transfer to Line 2).

[Bus 040](http://www.oasa.gr/xpmap.php?id=p040) from the port to Syntagma (near your hotel) runs every 30 min through the night, so it's probably a better bet.

As for the hotel, you should get in touch with them and make sure they understand you will be arriving very late, so they need to keep your room.

Comment: I wasn't very clear, but we are also arriving and staying late on Monday.  We arrive at the airport at 10:45pm and will need to go through Customs, and whatever else.  Is there a good bus service from the hotel as well?

Comment: Take Metro Line 3, direct from the airport to Syntagma.  Last train at 01:58 Fri/Sat, which you will definitely be able to catch; 23:58 otherwise, which may or may not be a bit of a squeeze depending on whether you have to go through Immigration, collect bags, etc.

Comment: That said, the golden rule of arriving in new unfamiliar cities late at night after long flights is: take a taxi.  Especially if you have bags to lug around.